# Can't run mongo on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm new on Mongodb, and after I run `mongo`, I get :

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-12-08T20:59:51.774+0100 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2019-12-08T20:59:51.775+0100 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2019-12-08T20:59:51.775+0100 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

Please any help!!

Comment: Have you started the mongod service? Use curl 127.0.0.1:27017 to check.

Comment: If you're totally new, you might not be aware that [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/index.html#mongo) is the command for the client shell, you need to run [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/index.html#mongod) to start the database service.